# Approval/Feedback workflow: how to change the task status with a custom button on InfoPath Form?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, infopath

I created two workflows, one based on the approval workflow and another based on the feedback workflow via SharePoint Designer 2010.

For both workflows I'm trying to find a solution to add a custom button to the InfoPath Form created for the task. When clicking the button, the task status should be updated to say something like "processing" for example to show that the assigned person is working on it.

Has anyone an idea or hint how I could achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

What I've done in the past is use conditional formatting to change a column when a specific event happens. So, the most common way this is done is when a certain field equals a certain value, it will automatically flip another field to a specific value you set, hide the field, or show a different feature thats not available unless that specific first field equals a certain value...

Maybe this might help you? (not affiliated with the business below)

[inclusivedesignsolutions.com link](http://www.inclusivedesignsolutions.com/infopath/infopath-conditional-formatting-showhide-optional-section-via-checkbox-or-radio-buttons/)

---

Here's another suggestion @jessica seeing your most recent comment.

You could have a status field with the status items of your choice and set workflow steps dependent on the choice within that field:

```
New Workflow

UPON CREATING NEW ITEM: 
If 'Current Item:Status' equals created 

> then email 'Current Item:CreatedBy'
(include email that notifies creator of item created?)

> then email 'Current Item:ModifiedBy'

(email instructs the user to go into the form and flip the status field to processing) 

<<<>>><<<>>>

New Workflow

UPON ITEM CHANGE: 
If 'Current Item:Status' equals processing 

> then email 'Current Item:CreatedBy'
(include email content here that you would show the creator at this time)

> then email 'Current Item:ModifiedBy'
(include email notifying them of item change)
```

Comment: Wanted to follow up to see if this solution works for you, or if you were looking for something else? @Jessica .

Comment: Hm... I'm not sure if this will help. To set any conditions for that there must be previous actions... but I cant't think of which could trigger what I want to achieve. The idea behind the additional button was to give the user an option to say like "hey, I saw the task and started working on it" and not just at the end when he's finished "yep it's done" like the standard workflow is.

Comment: Made an edit to my original answer. @jessica

Answer (score 0):

If you are using InfoPath, you can edit the form as you wish. So you can add another button for "Processing" status.

Otherwise, on SharePoint is list called "Tasks" it has it's own logic and choices for task status. Look at it and just create workflow on it.

*Hope this helps! :)*

*If so mark it as answer. Thank you.*